# How to create solution with multiple version support in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, version, class-library

I am creating one project in Asp.net MVC 4.7.1 latest version and want to reuse that solution as class library dll in other projects also. But other projects where we are using this dll not support latest version (4.6). When am trying to use the class library in other version solutions it throws below error.

> (0): error CS1705: Assembly 'ProjectName(dll name), Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

I need to create a solution with multiple version support while using it is as a dll.

Answer (score 0):

You need to target multiple frameworks in your project;

1. Right click on project name and click "Edit .cproj file"
2. add ( s ) to target framework tag so it becomes

```xml
<TargetFrameworks>...</TargetFrameworks>
```

3. specify your target frameworks (see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#supported-target-framework-versions) for all versions):

```xml
<TargetFrameworks>net472;net48;netcoreapp2.0;netcoreapp2.1;netcoreapp2.2</TargetFrameworks>
```

4. if your library will have any references, you need to specify manually all the references for each version:

```xml
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net471' ">
  <Reference Include="System.Net" />
</ItemGroup>
```

or specify reference for multiple versions:

```xml
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netcoreapp2.0' || '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netcoreapp2.1' || '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netcoreapp2.2' ">
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers" Version="1.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

or specify package reference for all target frameworks:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization" Version="1.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

you can specify the min required version and the framework will install the latest compatible version. e.g. below we specify Localization package min version as 1.0.0 but when it will be installed on .Net Core 2.2 it will install the newest compatible version, for more details about versioning see the [version ranges and wild chars](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/package-versioning#version-ranges-and-wildcards)

5. last but not least; in you code you need to check for target framework specific cases where you need to use compatible code line with each version.

for example to get culture info you need to specify different code for different .Net Core versions:

```cs
#if NETCOREAPP1_0
    var culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
#else
    var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
#endif

    _logger.LogInformation($"{culture.Name}");
```

if you are using visual studio, you will see a dropdown navigation for all target frameworks, you can use it to switch between target frameworks and check your code compatibility.

Comment: I have tried the suggestion as you have mentioned. But no luck. I have updated the code as below 
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net471' ">
    <PackageReference Include="System.Web.Mvc" Version="5.2.4.0" />
</ItemGroup>

Here we have mentioned the target framework condition. my scenario is Target framework is 4.6 and source dll is 4.7.1. 
My target having the system.web.mvc file in the version 5.2.3.0 and the dll that i am trying to refer 
to the 4.6 framework project having system.web.mvc as 5.2.4.0

Comment: can you add to the question your .csproj file?

Comment: I could not all the codes...it is a big project   <Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.5.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.Mvc.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>

 <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net471' ">
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Mvc" Version="5.2.4.0" />      
  </ItemGroup>

Comment: so you can reference an earlier version of referenced MVC, [see all available versions here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/)